# How to ask jquery to apply on one div when other div have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem here is that when i hover the specific div, the jquery script applys on every div with the same class. I'd like the script works only on the hovered element even if other divs have the same class. I don't have css ID's in this to make it easier.
Here is my jQuery code :

```
jQuery(".enprod_grille .isotope-container").hover(function() {
    // do this on hover
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .post-thumb').animate({
      'marginRight': '0px',
      'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .post-title').animate({
       'paddingLeft': '0px',
       'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .entry-content').animate({
       'paddingLeft': '0px',
       'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
},function() {
    // do this on hover out
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .post-thumb').animate({
       'marginRight': '45px',
       'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .post-title').animate({
       'paddingLeft': '20px',
       'opacity': '0'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery('.enprod_grille .entry-content').animate({
       'paddingLeft': '20px',
       'opacity': '0'
    }, 'fast');
});
```

Here is the link of the website, it appears in "En production" column on the bottom right : http://mwww.fr/fullhouse/?lang=fr

Comment: more information required past you `html ` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the current div using `this` like:

```
jQuery(".enprod_grille .isotope-container").hover(function() {
    // do this on hover
    jQuery(this).find('.post-thumb').animate({
        'marginRight': '0px',
        'opacity': '0.4'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery(this).find('.post-title').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery(this).find('.entry-content').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
}, function() {
    // do this on hover out
    jQuery(this).find('.post-thumb').animate({
        'marginRight': '45px',
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery(this).find('.post-title').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '20px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 'fast');
    jQuery(this).find('.entry-content').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '20px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.divname')[0]
$('.divname').get(0)
```

or of course:

```
$('.divname:first-child')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
jQuery(".enprod_grille .isotope-container").hover(
function() {

       var cont=jQuery(this).closest('.enprod_grille');
       // do this on hover
       cont.find('.post-thumb').animate({
        'marginRight': '0px',
        'opacity': '0.4'
        }, 'fast');

       cont.find('.post-title').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
        }, 'fast');

       cont.find('.entry-content').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '0px',
        'opacity': '1'
        }, 'fast');
     }
, 
function() {

       var cont=jQuery(this).closest('.enprod_grille');
       // do this on hover out
       cont.find('.post-thumb').animate({
        'marginRight': '45px',
        'opacity': '1'
        }, 'fast');

       cont.find('.post-title').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '20px',
        'opacity': '0'
        }, 'fast');

       cont.find('.entry-content').animate({
        'paddingLeft': '20px',
        'opacity': '0'
        }, 'fast');
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this example replace img background with image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Que</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .parent{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        }
        .text{
            position: absolute;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            opacity : 0;
        }
        .img{
            position: absolute;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="text"><span>a</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="text"><span>b</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="text"><span>c</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="text"><span>d</span></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('.text').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'margin-left' : -20,
            'opacity' : 1,
        },300);
        $(this).closest('.parent').find('.img').animate({
            'margin-left' : 40,
            'opacity' : 0.2,
        },300);
    });
    $('.text').on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.text').animate({
            'margin-left' : 0,
            'opacity' : 0
        },300);
        $('.img').animate({
            'margin-left' : 0,
            'opacity' : 1
        },300);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```